# iOS Charts Radar Chart size

Tags: ios-charts

I'm using the [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library and am trying to replicate this design:

[image]

I'm sort of getting there, but the chart is rendering itself way too small:

[image]

I'm expecting the chart to fill the entire width of the screen, and use all the vertical space. To be clear: the RadarChartView is the width of the entire black area, and the entire vertical space right up to the legend (which is not part of the chart view itself).

Any ideas?

This is the table cell code that shows the chart:

```swift
import Charts
import UIKit

final class ReportSpiderChart: UITableViewCell {
  private let labels = ["ARTISTS", "TRACKS", "ALBUMS"]

  @IBOutlet private var chartView: RadarChartView!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    chartView.webLineWidth = 1
    chartView.innerWebLineWidth = 1
    chartView.webColor = .init(hex: "28282A")
    chartView.innerWebColor = .init(hex: "28282A")
    chartView.legend.enabled = false

    let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
    xAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 11, weight: .semibold)
    xAxis.xOffset = 0
    xAxis.yOffset = 0
    xAxis.labelTextColor = .init(hex: "919198")
    xAxis.valueFormatter = self

    let yAxis = chartView.yAxis
    yAxis.labelCount = 3
    yAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 11, weight: .semibold)
    yAxis.labelTextColor = .init(hex: "919198")
    yAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    yAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
  }

  func configure(data: ReportData) {
    let entries: [RadarChartDataEntry] = [
      .init(value: Double(data.artists)),
      .init(value: Double(data.tracks)),
      .init(value: Double(data.albums)),
    ]

    chartView.yAxis.axisMaximum = Double(max(max(data.artists, data.tracks), data.albums))

    let dataSet = RadarChartDataSet(entries: entries)
    dataSet.fillColor = UIColor(hex: "FA4B4B").withAlphaComponent(0.75)
    dataSet.fillAlpha = 0.75
    dataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
    dataSet.lineWidth = 0
    dataSet.drawHighlightCircleEnabled = false
    dataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false)

    let data = RadarChartData(dataSets: [dataSet])
    data.setDrawValues(false)

    chartView.data = data
  }
}

extension ReportSpiderChart: IAxisValueFormatter {
  func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
    return labels[Int(value) % labels.count]
  }
}
```

Comment: try set chartView.minOffset = 0

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

It seems that their is a `spaceTop` and `spaceBottom` property on axis, did you try to set them to 0 on both axis ?

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/1bbec78109c7842d130d53ff8811bb6dbe865ba4/Source/Charts/Components/YAxis.swift#L72

Comment: No difference :(

Comment: Too bad :( Did you try inspecting with xcode inspector ? To see which view creates the spacing ?